# Grant with 'user'@'%' does not work, 'user '@'10.0.0.18' does work?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to debug some login issues of a webapp.

Here I grant privileges on the db machine:

```
mysql> grant all on *.* to 'thruser'@'%'  identified by  'a78jdv';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show grants for 'thruser';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for thruser@%                                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'thruser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '0c4ab18e7adb7f20' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I move over to the web server(which is IP 10.0.0.18, 10.0.0.19 is the db server), and try

```
$ mysql -u  thruser   --password=a78jdv -h 10.0.0.19
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'thruser'@'web01.e.nsoi.dk' (using password: YES)
```

That doesn't work - though why ?

Now, back on the db machine, and try something a bit different:

```
mysql> drop user 'thruser'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> grant all on *.* to 'thruser'@'10.0.0.18'  identified by  'a78jdv';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show grants for 'thruser'@'10.0.0.18';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for thruser@10.0.0.18                                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'thruser'@'10.0.0.18' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '0c4ab18e7adb7f20' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Over to the web server again, and run the same command as last time:

```
$ mysql -u  thruser   --password=a78jdv -h 10.0.0.19
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 178977
Server version: 5.1.51-community-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
...
```

What's going on ? Why would

```
 grant all on *.* to 'thruser'@'%'  identified by  'a78jdv';
```

not work - the host part is wildcarded, which should mean any/all hosts, while

```
 grant all on *.* to 'thruser'@'10.0.0.18'  identified by  'a78jdv';
```

does work ?

(I have done this also once more by issuing a FLUSH PRIVILEGES; after all the `grant`s, but the same results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have another user, with the name 'thruser', like 'thruser'@'localhost'?

If so, drop this local user, because '%' matches your localhost before your 'web01.e.nsoi.dk'.

More infos [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/connection-access.html)

Comment: I think that was it, though the other way round. there was an entry(in the mysql.user table) for host `web01.e.nsoi.dk` with an empty username. Once I deleted that row and did a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` it worked as expected.